# How to reference a summary item in another group ?

Tags: oraclereports

I have 2 groups ( A,B) , and a formula item in Group A which it's code references a summary item in group B , and i face rep-1517 error .

Comment: any help ,please ?

Comment: is not there any oracle develoeprs ?